# Plug-in manager cannot detect Module

Tags: ocean, petrel

I have installed the plug-in using the installer in Petrel 2012. When I open Petrel and see the Ocean Plug-in manager, it says that it cannot find the module.

What is the solution for this? How can I install the plug-in?

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to see if the plugin is installed, something like

> C:\xxx\Petrel 2012\PluginManager.exe /list C:\xxx\Petrel 2012\Petrel.exe

If the plugin doesn't list, try

> C:\xxx\Petrel 2012\PluginManager.exe /install /allusers thepip.pip
>   C:\xxx\Petrel 2012\Petrel.exe